# Run mysql in mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I finally install mysql cluster on two servers and got them running:

```
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @xx.xx.xx.xxx  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @yy.yyy.yyy.yyy  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @xx.xx.xx.xxx  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @xx.xx.xx.xx  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7)
id=5    @yy.yyy.yyy.yyy  (mysql-5.6.25 ndb-7.4.7)
```

But when i run mysql I only got this message:

```
The program "mysql" can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

I can not install these packages because they will conflict with the cluster.

my.conf

```
[mysqld]
# Options for mysqld process:
ndbcluster                      # run NDB storage engine

basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /usr/local/mysql/data
socket= /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


[mysql_cluster]
# Options for MySQL Cluster processes:
ndb-connectstring=46.21.99.140  # location of management server
```

My cluster is installed under /usr/local/mysql/

My error file do not show any errors
usr/local/mysql/data/mycomputer.err

Server1 is running fine with this setup but in is server2 mysql that is not starting.

Does anyone know why I get this message and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
The program "mysql" can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

> I can not install these packages because they will conflict with the
>   cluster.

I did fix the conflict and installd mysql-client-core-5.6 and everything works great!